# Nested FOREACH statements not working as I expected

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

In the first `foreach` statement, I have 4 `attendeeid`'s in the `attendees` table.

In the second `foreach`, I have 1 `attendeeid` in the `attend_date_temp` table.

I'm trying to load a `select box` with names from the `attendees` table, less the one in the `attend_date_temp` table.

I thought that, since the first `foreach` would loop 4 times, the second `foreach` would also loop 4 times. But it doesn't. It loops one time, causing the code in the second `foreach` to not execute and load the `select box` with names.

How can this be written so that the second `foreach` loops 4 times like the first `foreach` so the `select box` will have the names loaded to it?

```
// Load Button Clicked
if(isset($_POST['loadnames'])) {

    /* Read the history file and get the last record for each attendee for a particular group 
    and a particular member and write them to the attend_date_temp table if attend_date = CURDATE().*/
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT historyid, attend_date, attendeeid, groupid, memberid
                            FROM history 
                            WHERE groupid = :groupid
                            AND memberid = :memberid
                            AND attend_date = CURDATE()
                            ORDER BY historyid
                            DESC LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION['memberid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $aid = $row[2]; // set the attendeeid
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO attend_date_temp (attendeeid, groupid, memberid)
                                VALUES(:aid, :gid, :mid)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':aid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':gid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':mid', $_SESSION['memberid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }   

    $aaa = 0; // used to set the first select box entry to "Select"
    /* Load the Select Box with names, less the ones found in attend_date_temp Table. */
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT a.attendeeid, fname, lname, a.groupid, a.memberid, s.attendeeid, suspend
                            FROM attendees AS a
                            JOIN suspended AS s ON a.attendeeid = s.attendeeid 
                            WHERE a.memberid = :memberid
                            AND suspend = "N"
                            AND a.groupid = :groupid
                            ORDER BY lname');
    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION["memberid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("In the first loop"); </script>';

        $aid = $row[0];
        $lname = $row[2];
        $fname = $row[1];
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT attendeeid, memberid
                                FROM attend_date_temp
                                WHERE groupid = :groupid
                                AND attendeeid = :aid');
        $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':aid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result2 as $row2) { 
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("In the second loop"); </script>';

            // evaluate attendees attendeeid against attend_date_temp attendeeid
            if($row2['attendeeid'] != $aid){    

                // Load the flush Table with the IDs from the selected group
                if($_SESSION['flush'] == 0) {
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO flush (attendeeid, memberid)
                                                    VALUES(:attendeeid, :memberid)');
                    $stmt->bindValue(':attendeeid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION['memberid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->execute();
                } 
                if($aaa == 0) {
                    echo "<option value='Select'>Select</option>";
                    echo "<option value=".$aid.">".$lname.", ". $fname."</option>"; 
                    $aaa = 1;
                } else { 
                    echo "<option value=".$aid.">".$lname.", ". $fname."</option>"; 
                }  
            }  
        }  
    } 
    $_SESSION['flush'] = 1;
    exit();
} // last brace: loadnames
```

The attend_date_temp table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attend_date_temp`;
CREATE TABLE `attend_date_temp` (
`attendeeid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`groupid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`memberid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
KEY `attendeeid` (`attendeeid`),
KEY `memberid` (`memberid`),
CONSTRAINT `attend_date_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attendeeid`)  REFERENCES `attendees` (`attendeeid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `attend_date_temp_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`memberid`)   REFERENCES `members` (`memberid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The history table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `history`;
CREATE TABLE `history` (
`historyid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` float NOT NULL,
`subsidy` char(1) NOT NULL,
`last_payment` date NOT NULL,
`amount_paid` float NOT NULL,
`balance` float NOT NULL,
`attend` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
`attend_date` date NOT NULL,
`groupid` char(1) NOT NULL,
`attendeeid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`memberid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`historyid`),
KEY `attendeeid` (`attendeeid`),
CONSTRAINT `history_ibfk_15` FOREIGN KEY (`attendeeid`) REFERENCES `attendees` (`attendeeid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**UPDATE:**
This is a small part of a payment posting page. Names are loaded in the `select box` based on the group selected, then payments are posted by the name selected. This not only posts their payments but also their attendance. Once all the money has been collected, the remaining names not selected are marked as absent.

However, there are group members that attend groups that are not their own. When they make a payment, their money is posted and attendance recorded. BUT, and that's what this is all about, when that same person's group gets selected for payments, I don't want that person's name to get loaded. He's already paid, and his attendance has already been updated. To have him load again and be processed wld corrupt the history table. So I have to keep from double loading the same person. That's why I'm trying to use this attend_date_temp table.

Comment: They won't as long as you insist on using the same variable names, because all the second loop is doing is overwriting the values from the first

Comment: Why not just join attend_date_temp in the first query?

Comment: Mark: If you'll look closer, you'll see I have `alert`s set to show me the passes through the `foreach` loop. I get 4 `alert`s for the first `foreach` and only one for the second `foreach`. And I want the variables to change with each pass because I'm loading the names in a `select box`.

Comment: Kickstart: I tried that, but I cldn't get it to work. I don't know how to write that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix, use different variable names for the inner and outer loops:-

```
/* Load the Select Box with names, less the ones found in attend_date_temp Table. */
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT a.attendeeid, fname, lname, a.groupid, a.memberid, s.attendeeid, suspend
                            FROM attendees AS a
                            JOIN suspended AS s ON a.attendeeid = s.attendeeid 
                            WHERE a.memberid = :memberid
                            AND suspend = "N"
                            AND a.groupid = :groupid
                            ORDER BY lname');
    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION["memberid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("In the first loop"); </script>';

        $aid = $row[0];
        $lname = $row[2];
        $fname = $row[1];
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT attendeeid, memberid
                                FROM attend_date_temp
                                WHERE groupid = :groupid
                                AND attendeeid = :aid');
        $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':aid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result2 as $row2) { 
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("In the second loop"); </script>';

            // evaluate attendees attendeeid against attend_date_temp attendeeid
            if($row2['attendeeid'] != $aid){ 

                // Load the flush Table with the IDs from the selected group
                if($_SESSION['flush'] == 0) {
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO flush (attendeeid, memberid)
                                                    VALUES(:attendeeid, :memberid)');
                    $stmt->bindValue(':attendeeid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION['memberid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->execute();
                } 
                if($aaa == 0) {
                    echo "<option value='Select'>Select</option>";
                    echo "<option value=".$aid.">".$lname.", ". $fname."</option>"; 
                    $aaa = 1;
                } else { 
                    echo "<option value=".$aid.">".$lname.", ". $fname."</option>"; 
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

To do a join you would do something like this:-

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT a.attendeeid, fname, lname, a.groupid, a.memberid, s.attendeeid, suspend, adt.attendeeid AS adt_attendeeid, adt.memberid AS adt_memberid
                        FROM attendees AS a
                        INNER JOIN suspended AS s ON a.attendeeid = s.attendeeid 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN attend_date_temp adt ON adt.groupid = a.groupid AND adt.attendeeid = a.attendeeid
                        WHERE a.memberid = :memberid
                        AND suspend = "N"
                        AND a.groupid = :groupid
                        AND adt.groupid IS NULL
                        ORDER BY lname');
$stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION["memberid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

EDIT

Think it can be more simply done like this (not tested so please excuse any typos)

```
<?php

    $first = true;

/* Load the Select Box with names, less the ones found in attend_date_temp Table. */
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT a.attendeeid, fname, lname
                            FROM attendees AS a
                            INNER JOIN suspended AS s ON a.attendeeid = s.attendeeid 
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN attend_date_temp adt ON adt.groupid = a.groupid AND adt.attendeeid = a.attendeeid
                            WHERE a.memberid = :memberid
                            AND suspend = "N"
                            AND a.groupid = :groupid
                            AND adt.groupid IS NULL
                            ORDER BY lname');
    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION["memberid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $aid = $row[0];
        $lname = $row[2];
        $fname = $row[1];

        // Load the flush Table with the IDs from the selected group
        if($_SESSION['flush'] == 0) 
        {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO flush (attendeeid, memberid)
                                            VALUES(:attendeeid, :memberid)');
            $stmt->bindValue(':attendeeid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION['memberid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        } 
        if($first) 
        {
            echo "<option value='Select'>Select</option>";
            echo "<option value='".$aid."'>".$lname.", ". $fname."</option>"; 
            $first = false;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "<option value='".$aid."'>".$lname.", ". $fname."</option>"; 
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Kickstart: I changed the second `foreach` loop to reflect `$result2` and `$row2`, but still got one loop only out of it. Your suggested query produced in the `select box` only one name, the one I'm trying to omit. This has been eating my lunch for two days. But thanks for your time and help. I appreciate you.

Comment: Fixed the extra query. However is the purpose of the 2nd loop to just have a list of people to avoid putting out? If so do you want to put out a row if no record is found on _attend_date_temp_ ? If so you need to process even when no rows have been returned. Have you the table declares and a few sample rows of data, along with the output your require?

Comment: Kickstart: I'll Edit my post and show the entire process I'm using to loa only names that don't get added to the `attend_date_temp` table. And I'll provide the tables. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added a suggestion.

Comment: Nice work, Kickstart. Perfect. I don't understand how a `left join` really works, but I'm certainly going to look into it. Absolutely perfect! Thanks a million =)